# "me and the other" or "I and the other"?

Tags: word-usage, personal-pronouns

this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362486/size-of-the-hypothesis-space) says

> I'm asking the same question as the linked one, I simply don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but hopefully, this one will more clearly explain what `me` and the other asker both mean

In this case, would "I" be better? or any other better expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what me and the other asker both mean

This use is idiomatic if not strictly correct.

If you take out `and the other asker` the sentence becomes:

> what me mean

Which as you can see, is terrible!

> what I and the other asker both mean

This is better but I was always taught in school to use `X and I`

> what the other asker and I both mean

I'm still not 100% sure about the position of *both* but either of the last two would not set my teeth on edge, and I would hear being used certainly in speech. (as a native BrE speaker)